# filter lisbox populated by an observable collection by the class type in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, listbox, observablecollection

I'm creating a program where I need to populate a listbox with cars, bikes, and vans. I created classes for this:

```
public class Vehicle
    {
        protected string Make { get; set; }
        protected string Model { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        protected string Year { get; set; }
        protected string Colour { get; set; }
        public string Mileage { get; set; }
        protected string Description { get; set; }
        protected string Engine { get; set; }

        public Vehicle() { }

        public Vehicle(string make, string model, string price, string colour, string year, string milage, string description, string engine)
        {
            Make = make;
            Model = model;
            Price = price;
            Year = year;
            Mileage = milage;
            Description = description;
            Engine = engine;
            Colour = colour;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Make:  {0}    Model:  {1} \n Price:  {2}    Mileage:  {3} \n", Make, Model, Price, Mileage);
        }

        public virtual string vehicleDetails()
        {
            return string.Format("Make: {0} \nModel{1} \nPrice {2} \n Year {3} \n Colour: {4}, Mileage: {5} /nDescription: {6} /n Engine: {7}", Make, Model, Price, Year, Colour, Mileage, Description, Engine);
        }

        public virtual string FileFormat()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}", Make, Model, Price, Year, Colour, Mileage, Description, Engine);

        }
    }

    public class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public enum BodyType { Convertible, Hatchback, Coupe, Estate, MPV, SUV, Saloon, Unlisted };
        public BodyType Body { get; set; }

        public Car(string make, string model, string price, string colour, string year, string milage, string description, string engine, BodyType body)
            : base(make, model, price, colour, year, milage, description, engine)
        {
            Body = body;
        }
        public override string vehicleDetails()
        {
            return base.vehicleDetails() + string.Format("body type {0}\n", Body);
        }

        public override string FileFormat()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}, {8}", Make, Model, Price, Year, Colour, Mileage, Description, Engine, Body);
        }
    }

    public class Bike : Vehicle
    {
        public enum BikeType { Scooter, TrailBike, Sports, Commuter, Tourer };
        public BikeType Btype { get; set; }

        public Bike(string make, string model, string price, string colour, string year, string milage, string description, string engine, BikeType bType)
            : base(make, model, price, colour, year, milage, description, engine)
        {
            Btype = bType;
        }
        public override string vehicleDetails()
        {
            return base.vehicleDetails() + string.Format("type {0}\n", Btype);
        }

        public override string FileFormat()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}, {8}", Make, Model, Price, Year, Colour, Mileage, Description, Engine, Btype);
        }
    }

    public class Van : Vehicle
    {
        public enum WheelBase { Short, Medium, Long, Unlisted };
        public WheelBase WBase { get; set; }

        public enum VanType { CombiVan, Dropside, PanelVan, Pickup, Tipper, Unlisted }
        public VanType VType { get; set; }

        public Van(string make, string model, string price, string colour, string year, string milage, string description, string engine, WheelBase wBase, VanType vType)
            : base(make, model, price, colour, year, milage, description, engine)
        {
            WBase = wBase;
            VType = vType;
        }
        public override string vehicleDetails()
        {
            return base.vehicleDetails() + string.Format("wheel base {0}\n Van Type {1} ", WBase, VType);
        }

        public override string FileFormat()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}, {8}", Make, Model, Price, Year, Colour, Mileage, Description, Engine, WBase, VType);
        }
    }
}
```

I am then adding them all to an observable collection, (the adding will be via user input in the future but for now I am adding them in code.

```
Car car4 = new Car("Audi", "A6", "19000", "Red", "20014", "20000", "hannnnndy", "2litre", Car.BodyType.Saloon);

            vehicles.Add(car1);
            vehicles.Add(car2);
            vehicles.Add(car3);
            vehicles.Add(car4);

            Van van1 = new Van("Ford", "transit", "25000", "white", "2008", "100000", "lovely red car", "1.4litre", Van.WheelBase.Medium, Van.VanType.Unlisted);
            Van van2 = new Van("Citroen", "berlingo", "2000", "silver", "2006", "20100", "lovely", "1.4litre", Van.WheelBase.Long, Van.VanType.PanelVan);
```

They are then being added to a listboux, i was using lisbox.ItemsSource for this but I can change this to listbox.Items.Add if needed
I then have to filter the listbox showing either, all the vehicles, all the cars, all the vans, or all the bikes. I have made attempts at this.

```
 private void radioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as RadioButton;
        string selected = button.Content.ToString();
        if(selected != null)
        {
            if (selected == "all")
            {

            }
            else if(selected == "cars")
            {
                var collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
                collectionViewSource.Source = vehicles.;
                foreach (object Car in vehicles)
                {

                    lbxVehicles.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource
                }
            }
            else if(selected == "bikes")
            {
                foreach (object Bike in vehicles)
                {
                    lbxVehicles.Items.Add(Bike);
                }
            }
```

these are a few different ways I was thinking one could possibly filter the listbox but I don't know if they can work or if I am going about it completely the wrong way, it also has to be filtered VIA a radiobutton.
If you could explain your possible solutions that would be great because I am not very advanced when it comes to this and would like to learn all I can.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to filter an `IEnumerable<T>` by `Type`. For example :

```
var bikes = vehicles.OfType<Bike>().ToList();
var cars = vehicles.OfType<Car>().ToList();
```

Comment: Worked perfect and is easy to understand. Thanks very much.